# How do we check if a function returns mutiple values in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-value, return-type

This question was [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698329/python-basics-how-to-check-if-a-function-returns-mutiple-values), but I wish to ask something subtly different.

How do we determine if a python function returns multiple values, **without calling the function**? Is there some way to find out at something more *like* compile-time instead of at run-time? (I realize that python is an interpreted language)

The following is out of the question:

```
r = demo_function(data) # takes more than 5 minutes to run
if (not len(r) == 2) or (not isinstance(r, tuple)):
    raise ValueError("I was supposed to return EXACTLY two things")
```

So is:

```
try:
    i, j = demo_function(data)
    # I throw TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("Hey! I was expecting two values.")
except TypeError:
    s1 = "Hey! I was expecting two values."
    s2 = "Also, TypeError was thrown, not ValueError"
    raise ValueError(s1 + s2)
```

The following sort of works, but is extremely inelegant:

```
r = demo_function(extremely_pruned_down_toy_data) # runs fast
if len(r) != 2:
    raise ValueError("There are supposed to be two outputs")
# Now we run it for real
r = demo_function(data) # takes more than 5 minutes to run
```

There are tools already in python which do similar things. For example, we can find out if a class object has a certain attribute:

```
prop_str = 'property'
if not hasattr(obj, prop_str):
    raise ValueError("There is no attribute named" + prop_str + " NOOOOoooo! ")
```

Also, we can find out how many **INPUTS** a function has:

```
from inspect import signature

sig = signature(demo_function)
p = sig.parameters
if len(p)) != 2:
raise ValueError("The function is supposed to have 2 inputs, but it has" + str(p))
```

I basically want the following:

```
p = nargout(demo_function)
if p != 2:
    raise ValueError("The function is supposed to have 2 outputs, but it has" + str(p))
```

Asking what a function returns is one of the most basic things questions one can ask about a function. It feels really weird that I'm having trouble finding out.

### EDIT:

juanpa.arrivillaga wrote,

[...] fundamentally, this points to a deeper, underlying design flaw: why do you have functions that can return different length containers when you are expecting a specific length?

Well, let me explain. I have something like this:

```
def process_data(data_processor, data):
    x, y =  data_processor(data)
    return x, y
```

A precondition of the `process_data` function is that the input `data_processor` **MUST** return two items. As such, I want to write some error checking code to enforce the precondition.

```
def process_data(data_processor, data):
    # make sure data_processor returns exactly two things!
    verify_data_processor(data_processor)
    x, y =  data_processor(data)
    return x, y
```

However, it looks like that's not easily doable.

Comment: The issue is that a function can have many return statements but it will only ever actually return one value, and what is returned depends on the execution of the function's code: it need not even be the same type each time it's run. Ideally the developer should describe the return value in a docstring

Comment: The return value is whatever **return** statement gets executed.  Or None if at the end.  Cpt obvious here but: it may be bad form, but the dev could return an instance at one point, a tuple at another, an int next...  So there is no way to know.  You could wrap the function and enforce your own wishes, I suppose, that's what I would do, but that wasn't your question.

Answer (score 5):

A function really only has a **single return value**. It can return a container, such as a `tuple`, of whatever length. But there is no inherent way for a Python function to know the length of such a value, Python is much too dynamic. Indeed, in general, the interpreter does not know the nature of the return value of a function. But even if we stick to just considering functions that return containers, consider the following function:

```
def howmany(n):
    return n*('foo',)
```

Well, what should `nargout(howmany)` return?

And python does not special case something like `return x, y`, nor should it, because then what should be the behavior when the length of the returned container *is* indeterminate, such as `return n*(1,)`? No, it is up to the caller to deal with the case of a function returning a container, in one of the ways you've already illustrated.

And fundamentally, this points to a deeper, underlying design flaw: why do you have functions that can return different length containers when you are expecting a specific length?