# Unpack positional arguments from data structure in Python

Tags: python

given:

```
def psum(a,b,c):
    return a**b+c
```

and `x = [1,2]` and `y = 3`
how can I do `psum(*x,3)` --> an equivalent.

I do not want to do `x[0], x[1]` because a function returns `x` and calling it twice would be inefficient. Could one do `z = function(a)`. where `z = x`. and then do `z[0]`, `z[1]`.

But I'm wondering if one can do this otherwise and use positional arguments in such a way.

Also, *without* using a wrapper.

Edit: One cannot use names because I didn't implement the function and the function writers did not use named arguments :/

Comment: Also, note that if you have `x` -- `x = func(...)`, then you can index `x` naturally.  It won't call the function again.  `x = func(); psum(x[0],x[1],3)` only calls `func` once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
psum(*x + [y])
```

Comment: it works! and he winss :). you can do any order of *x + [2], [2] + x... etc it seems. now what about interspersed keyword and positional e.g. func(a=2,b,c,d=7) ;)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the order of your arguments doesn't matter, so `psum(3,*x)` will work.

In the slightly-more-general case, if you know the names of the arguments,

```
psum(*x,c=3)
```

seems to work for me as well, but it won't work if `sum` is defined so that it takes varargs ...

I don't think there is a way to do this in the completely general case without modifying the object you pass to `psum`:

```
x.append(3)
psum(*x)
```

Comment: sorry. fixed. order matters. i'm thinking ideally plot(x,y,z) is my problem and i'm using meshgrid(x,y) to get x,y

Comment: I think you can do something like `x_out,y_out = meshgrid(x,y)` so that the result is two separate objects.

Comment: The problem is that named arguments cannot follow a `*` pointer type expression. So either name all of the arguments, or write the function to handle an iterable, or use `*args` and `**kwargs` in the definition. I don't think this is very satisfactory on Python's part, but it is what it is.

Comment: @Eiyrioü von Kauyf, check out meshgrid's docs: [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.htm). The main use case is such that you get two separate objects back, rather than a tuple of them.

Comment: @EMS: wrong. 1. Named arguments may follow `*`expression: `f(*[1,2],c=3)` is legal 2.[A function always returns a single object in Python (it may be a tuple)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/61636/4279).

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant *unnamed* arguments cannot follow. I thought it was clear what I meant and it was too late to edit the comment. Notice how I say right after that naming all the arguments could be a solution.

Comment: Also, you can unpack the output automatically, as in the linked example from NumPy. It's syntactic sugar, sure, but probably solves the OP's problem.

Comment: @EMS yeah but I want to do plot_wireframe(*meshgrid(x,y),Z) if you get what I mean.. more of the unpythonic-shortness thing ;).

Comment: In that case, I would *highly* suggest storing the output to variables first. If it's just an ad hoc plotting script, then it's just a matter of inconvenience for you to write the extra assignment. If it's in a script meant to be used by someone else, the readability matters a lot more than trying to jam it all into a one liner.