# Different number of return values in Python function

Tags: python

Is it okay/good practice to return different number of return values from a function in Python? If yes, how should the caller handle the return values? e.g.

```
def func():
    if(condition_1):
        return 1,2
    if(condition_2):
        return 1
    if(condition_3):
        return 1,2,3,4
```

**Note:**
condition_1,condition_2 and condition_3 are local to the function func so the caller has no idea how many values will be returned.

Comment: best is to return a list with values. It is good to have consistency in program.

Comment: You can use tuples as well.

Comment: You are only returning one object in each case, two of them are tuples.  Personally I would always return the same type of object, even in the single value case, for consistency, but that's subjective.

Comment: Although duplicate offer is quite similar, there are some important key differences, like different number of returned values. So it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

[Is it pythonic for a function to return multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61605/is-it-pythonic-for-a-function-to-return-multiple-values) have a great explanation in this.

But in your case, it depends on your use-case. If you know how to handle returning data, then there is no problem in using this. Like:

```
def func():
    if(condition_1):
        return a,b
    if(condition_2):
        return (a, )
    if(condition_3):
        return c,d,e,f
    if(condition_4):
        return a,b

vals = func()
if len(vals) == 2:
    # We are sure that we will get `a,b` in return
    do something ...
elif len(vals) == 3:
    ...
```

In example above, function that will process `vals` tuple knows how to handle returning data according to some criteria. It have 2 `return` possibilities that returns the same data!

If you know *exactly* how to handle data, then it is ok to go with different number of returns. The key point in here is **functions do a single job**. If your have problems in recognizing the return values, then your function is doing more than one job or you must avoid using different number of arguments.

Answer (score 6):

It's okay to return multiple values, but you must keep all your returns in same form/type for using:

```
def func():
    if(condition_1):
        return 1, 2
    if(condition_2):
        return 1,    # return a tuple same as the others
    if(condition_3):
        return 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 6):

I would avoid this. In general (although there are occasionally exceptions), as other people have mentioned, it is a good idea to return the same type of object from each branch of a function. However, this goes deeper than just wrapping singular return values in one-element tuples  - consider a pattern whereby you return the same number of things (in the same order), and using `None` or some type-specific 'null' value (the [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)) for any that don't apply to that branch.

This means client code can *always* do this:

```
a, b, c, d, e = func()
```

and ignore any values it doesn't care about. With the null object pattern also in the mix, then even code that cares about the potentially non-existent values might not have to special case them. If you vary the length of the tuple, *every* call has to be prepared for the results of *any* branch, which means it nearly has to match your branches.

A really nice way, for you and for calling code, to enforce this kind of pattern is to use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). This also has the nice benefit of making your code immediately more self-documenting.

Answer (score 2):

While this is subjective, I like to return dictionaries - it helps to avoid caring for the order of what is returned, I can have a partial return (3 elements out of 5 for instance) and it makes the code more readable.

```
def func():
    if(condition_1):
        return {'name': 'Joe', 'age': 32}
    if(condition_2):
        return {'name': 'Mary'}

res = func()
name = res.get('name', 'unknown')
age = res.get('age', 0)
```

Comment: Tuples are ordered too. Alse they can be sliced like lists too. The difference is only in mutability. Lists can be changed when tuples are immutable.

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy: it is less the order itself which is important for me, rather the fact that I return `{'age': 32, 'name': 'Joe'}` instead of `32, 'Joe'`. In the first case I know I must `.get()` a value, in the other one I usually need to check in which order I returned the data.

Comment: If all your dict keys are guaranteed to be strings, I would use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) and use sensible defaults in the returned value, instead of having to have the calling code second guess it like this.