# How do i return two separate DataFrames from a single DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, function, split, return

Im performing some operation within the dataframe and then splitting it into two dataframes. my problem is when i use the **return** function it combines both dataframes and return them as a **tuple** instead of two separate dataframes.

```
def block_dsgn(design,clmn='a',val=-1):
 
if design[clmn].eq(val).any():
    blck1 = pd.DataFrame(design[design[clmn]==val])
    blck2 = pd.DataFrame(design[design[clmn]!= val])
return blck1, blck2
    

if ~ design[clmn].eq(val).any():
    return 'check block factor value...val parameter'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternatives for returning multiple values from a Python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/alternatives-for-returning-multiple-values-from-a-python-function)

Comment: See also: [Is it pythonic for a function to return multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61605/is-it-pythonic-for-a-function-to-return-multiple-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
def block_dsgn(design,clmn='a',val=-1):
 
  if design[clmn].eq(val).any():
      blck1 = pd.DataFrame(design[design[clmn]==val])
      blck2 = pd.DataFrame(design[design[clmn]!= val])
  return blck1, blck2

a, b = block_dsgn(...)
```

a and b are two separate dataframes

Comment: in a way. i want the function to generate that, instead of me having to split it outside of the function.