# Is it possible to assign two different returned values from a python function to two separate variables?

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to assign two different returned values from a python function to two separate variables.

Here's the function, which returns a **name** and **city** value.

def authenticate():

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?    ")

city = raw_input("What city do you live in?    ")


if name != "Jerry Seinfeld" or city != "New York":
    print """

    Access denied

    """

else:
    print """


    Authenticated

    """
    return name and city
```

Now, I want to assign the returned values to two variables, **a and b**.

I only know how to assign one value, like this.

a = authenticate()

(this actually assigns the city value to a, which I'm guessing is because "return name" comes before "return city" in the code)

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you return multiple values in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate. This asks "how, and how to catch?", that asks "which?".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python supports **tuple unpacking**.

```
def foo():
  return 'bar', 42

a, b = foo()
```

It even works with other sequences.

```
a, b = [c, d]
```

Python 3.x extends the syntax.

```
a, b, *c = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change `return name and city`(because "and"s use is logical expressions) to `return (name, city)` for returning a tuple. Now you can assign values with tuple unpacking:

```
name,city = authenticate()
```

Answer (score 0):

if a function return more values you can use

```
a,b = zip(*function_calling())
```