# How to return multiple values from *args?

Tags: python

I have a `hello` function and it takes n arguments (see below code).

```
def hello(*args):
  # return values
```

I want to return multiple values from `*args`. How to do it? For example:

```
d, e, f = hello(a, b, c)
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
def hello(*args):
  values = {} # values
  rst = [] # result
  for arg in args:
    rst.append(values[arg])
  return rst

a, b, c = hello('d', 'e', f)
a, b = hello('d', 'f')
```

Just return list. :) :D

Comment: No sure what you mean. `return args` will return multiple values from `*args`.

Comment: Duplicate , answered in detail here.   

[Stack overflow ret mul val python][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python

Comment: In hello function I'm assigning values to variables. I get that variables from *args. You know args are dynamic. So I don't know return multiple values from dynamic variables /args/ like example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, you want to return a new tuple with the same length as args (i.e. len(args)), and whose values are computed from args[0], args[1], etc.
Note that you can't modify 'args' directly, e.g. you can't assign args[0] = xxx, that's illegal and will raise a TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment.
What You need to do then is return a *new* tuple whose length is the same as len(args).
For example, if you want your function to add one to every argument, you can do it like this:

```
def plus_one(*args):
    return tuple(arg + 1 for arg in args)
```

Or in a more verbose way:

```
def plus_one(*args):
    result = []
    for arg in args: result.append(arg + 1)
    return tuple(result)
```

Then, doing :

```
d, e, f = plus_one(1, 2, 3)
```

will return a 3-element tuple whose values are 2, 3 and 4.

The function works with any number of arguments.

Comment: You know 'args' arguments are dynamic. How to return multiple values from dynamic 'args'? Sorry for poor english. Please see my comment.

Comment: Woow. Better solution than me. Thank you for sharing your knowledge. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just return a tuple:

```
def hello(*args):
    return 1, 2, 3
```

...or...

```
    return (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

args is a list. if you return a sequence (list, tuple), Python will try to iterate and assign to your d, e, f variables. so following code is ok.

```
def hello(*args):
   return args

d, e,  f = hello(1,2,3)
```

As long as you have, the right number of values in the *args list. It will be assigned to your variables. If not, il will raise a ValueError exception.

```
d, e, f = hello(1, 2) #raise ValueError
```

I hope ith helps

Answer (score 0):

Just return them. For instance, if you want to return the parameters unmodified, do this:

```
def hello(*args):
    return args
```

If you want to return something else, return that instead:

```
def hello(*args):
    # ...
    # Compute d, e and f
    # ...
    return d, e, f
```