# Returning every element from a list (Python)

Tags: python, return, return-value, multiple-variable-return

I know that it is possible for a function to return multiple values in Python. What I would like to do is return each element in a list as a separate return value. This could be an arbitrary number of elements, depending on user input. I am wondering if there is a pythonic way of doing so?

For example, I have a function that will return a pair of items as an array, e.g., it will return `[a, b]`.

However, depending on the input given, the function may produce multiple pairs, which will result in the function returning `[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]`. Instead, I would like it to return `[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]`

As of now, I have implemented a very shoddy function with lots of temporary variables and counts, and am looking for a cleaner suggestion.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: It's not entirely true to say the python functions can return more than one value: such functions actually return a tuple, which is unpacked on assignment. So you can simply convert your list to a tuple using `tuple()`. If what you mean is that you want to return them one-at-a-time on multiple calls, well then you're using `yield` and building a generator, something else entirely.

Comment: It's worth noting tuples are only the norm when it comes to 'returning multiple values'. You can happily return a list and unpack it just like a tuple.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python) statement which matches perfectly for this usecase.

```
def foo(a):
    for b in a:
        yield b
```

This will return a generator which you can iterate.

```
print [b for b in foo([[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]])
```

Comment: Not what he asked, but probably what he really wants.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Btw. she's a she. :)

Answer (score 12):

When a python function executes:

```
return a, b, c
```

what it actually returns is the tuple `(a, b, c)`, and tuples are unpacked on assignment, so you can say:

```
x, y, z = f()
```

and all is well. So if you have a list

```
mylist = [4, "g", [1, 7], 9]
```

Your function can simply:

```
return tuple(mylist)
```

and behave like you expect:

```
num1, str1, lst1, num2 = f()
```

will do the assignments as you expect.

If what you *really* want is for a function to return an indeterminate number of things as a sequence that you can iterate over, then you'll want to make it a generator using `yield`, but that's a different ball of wax.

Comment: This is really the solution to what it is being asked in this question. Not sure why another answer was chosen

Comment: Just `return mylist` leads to the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very simple just join the elements of list by providing a required separator

Syntax for join method :

```
"separator".join(iterable)
```

For example let us consider a function where you need to return all the list values separated by a comma (,)

```
def fun(samp_list):
    return ",".join(samp_list)

print(fun(["1","2","3"]))
```

And the answer as follows

```
1,2,3
```

Example 2 : Return list values separated by a new line

```
def fun(samp_list):
   return "/n".join(samp_list)

print(fun(["1","2","3"]))
```

And the output for this function is as follows

```
1
2
3
```

Hope it's useful

Do support by upvoting !

Comment: Welcome on stack overflow, I think the OP is looking for a tuple of python variable. with the `join` function output is a string and cannot be used afterward

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question:
[How to return multiple values from *args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381739/how-to-return-multiple-values-from-args)

The important idea is return values, as long as they're a container, can be expanded into individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

> However, depending on the input given, the function may produce multiple pairs, which will result in the function returning [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]. Instead, I would like it to return [a, b], [c, d], [e, f]

Can you not just use the returned list (i.e. the list [[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]) and extract the elements from it? Seems to meet your criteria of arbitrary number of / multiple values.

Comment: You can just use `tuple()` to convert the list to a tuple. Python multi-valued functions actually return a tuple, which is automatically unpacked on assignment.

Comment: I ended up doing something quite like this, based on the functionality of the caller method. But @wenzul suggestion is likely more pythonic, and I may rewrite it to use the more concise `yield`. Thanks guys!