# How can I use the result from a function in another function?

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

Suppose I have a function like:

```
def eklid(p, a, b,):
    x = [1, 0]
    y = [0, 1]
    r = [a, b]
    q = [0]
    n = 0
    while r[n+1] != 0:
        q.append(r[n] // r[n+1])
        r.append(r[n] % r[n+1])
        x.append(x[n] - x[n+1] * q[n+1])
        y.append(y[n] - y[n+1] * q[n+1])

        if p == 0:
            print(r[n], "=", r[n+1], "*", q[n+1], "+", r[n+2])
        elif p == 1:    # extended print
            print(r[n+2], "\t", x[n+2], "\t", y[n+2], "\t", r[n+2], "=", a, "*", x[n+2], "+", b, "*", y[n+2])
        elif p == -1:
            k =1
        else:
            print("wrong input")
        n += 1
    return x, y, r, q, n,
```

I want to use `x` and `r` from it in this function:

```
    def cong_solv(x, r, b,):
        result = x/r
        int_result = int(result)
        return int_result
```

How can I do that?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51422967

Answer (score 3):

```
# Here, a=x, b=y, c=r, d=q, e=n
a, b, c, d, e = eklid(h, i, k)

# Assuming based on your function definitions you want the
# same value as the third argument
final_result = cong_solv(a, c, k)
```

You get the return values from `eklid` and save them into variables.  You then use those variables to call the next function.

Of course, in a real code you should name your varialbes better than I did in this example.  I deliberately did not call the variables the same names as inside the function to demonstrate that you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to call the eklid() function from inside the cong_solv() function. Something like this should work:

```
def cong_solv(x, r, b):
   p = "foo"
   b = "bar"
   x, y, r, q, n = eklid(p, a, b)

   result = x/r 
   int_result = int(result) 
   return int_result
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, when you return more than one variable, it returns a tuple.
You can retrieve the value by its index (returned_value[0], returned_value[1]) or unpack the tuple like Mike Driscoll said (a, b, c, d = eklid(h, i, k)).

Since I got two downvotes, I am going to give you better (I hope) explanation:
Everytime you return more than one value, it returns a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

```
def my_function():
   a = 10
   b = 20
   return a, b

print type(my_function()) # <type 'tuple'>
```

But if you return just one value:

```
def my_function():
    a = 10
    return a

print type(my_function()) # <type 'int'>
```

So if you want to use your value, you can:

Unpack tuple values like this

```
a, b = my_function()
```

This way you get your return values in the same order you return inside my_function.

Rewriting your code, you can simply do:

```
a, b, c = eklid(10, 20, 30) # it will return a tuple
```

And call your other function:

```
cong_solv(a, b, 20)
```

In my honest opinion I would return a [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). With dict you can be explicit because your values have key names.

Inside your eklid return function:

```
return d # d = {"what_x_means": x,
         #      "what_y_means": y,
         #      "what_r_means": r,
         #      "what_q_means": q, 
         #      "what_n_means": n}
```

And retrieve for its key:

```
d["what_x_means"]
d["what_r_means"]
```

Comment: Any reason to downvote? I was the first to say that it returns a tuple. The OP did not know such a thing. I think it was the goal of his question.

Comment: Compare your answer with those that got upvotes, and notice the differences.  Being the first to answer doesn't mean that your answer is the best one.  Offhand, I'd say that introducing a new term to the OP without explaining what it means is probably not ideal, given the OP's level of knowledge. Part of your answer just repeats what another person said in their answer, which is not particularly useful.

Answer (score -2):

Similar to [How do you return multiple values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python)

1. Return as an tuple (x,y,r....) or an array and assign to tuple / array respectively.
2. Or assign them to class variables and access them

Comment: This does not answer the question; OP already knows how to return the values. The question is about accessing them.