# Use the result of the return of one function in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know there are several questions about this, I read but I could not understand. I'm trying to use the result of the return of one function in another:

```
def multiplication(a):
    c = a*a
    return c

def subtraction(c):
    d = c - 2
    return d

print(subtraction(c))
```

**Output:**

> NameError: name 'c' is not defined

I know that there is a possibility of using global variables, but I have seen that this is not a good idea since the variables can change their value.

EDIT:

These two functions are just idiotic examples. I have two functions with words and I need to use the return of the first function in the second function. In case of this my idiotic example, I need the result of the first function (c) in the second function.

Comment: `print(subtraction(c))` what is `c` here?

Comment: What are you specifically trying to do? You want to multiply something and subtract something? What actual calculation are you trying to do?

Comment: Change to c to a value? Even global variable, you have to have a value or ANYTHING for python to RUN....

Comment: `c` is just a local variable, it doesn't exit outside the `multiplication` function. To use the result of the function, you have to call the function.

Comment: For cases where multiple values are returned as a tuple, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256989.

Comment: In order for there to be a "result of the first function" to use in the second function, it at least has to be called somewhere first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling your functions properly.

```
def multiplication(a):
    c = a*a
    return c

def subtraction(c):
    d = c - 2
    return d

# first store some value in a variable
a = 2

# then pass this variable to your multiplication function
# and store the return value
c = multiplication(a)

# then pass the returned value to your second function and print it
print(subtraction(c))
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this makes things clearer?

```
def multiplication(a):
    c = a*a
    return c

def subtraction(c):
    d = c - 2
    return d

print(multiplication(5))               # 25
print(subtraction(5))                  #  3
print(multiplication(subtraction(5)))  #  9
print(subtraction(multiplication(5)))  # 23
```

I think you're trying to do what's happing in the last print statement: first call the multiplication function, and then call the subtraction function on the result.

---

Note that the variable `c` in your multiplication function is an entirely different variable from the `c` in your subtraction function. So much so, that it may make things more clear to rename your variables, perhaps something like this:

```
def multiplication(a):
    product = a * a
    return product

def subtraction(a):
    difference = a - 2
    return difference
```

Answer (score 1):

So why not use return value?

```
print(subtraction(multiplication(24)))
```

?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20347703)

Comment: Oh really? Sp, my reply does not say anything about how "to use the result of the return of one function in another", does it?

Answer (score 1):

'c' is not declared outside the 'subtraction' function.
You need to give need to declare 'c' before printing.
Let's say you want 'c' to be 5, then:

```
c = 5
print(subtraction(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined two functions which both return a number.

If you call `subtraction(c)` you will get the error you see, because there is no `c`.

If you define a `c` in scope of the print statmenet

```
c = 42
print(subtraction(c))
```

it will be ok.

Try thinking of it like this: each function takes a variable does things to it and returns a number.

e.g.

```
>>> multiplication(101)
10201
```

That this happened to be called `c` *isnide* the function isn't known *outside* the function (i.e scope).

You can save the number to a variable

```
>>> x = multiplication(101)
```

Then `x` remembers that value.
Or

```
>>> c = multiplication(101)
```

This is not the same `c` as you have *inside* the functions.

---

(And after the question edit):

Decide what value you want to call the first function with, for example 101:

```
>>> c = multiplication(101)
```

then use that return to call the next function:

```
>>>> subtraction(c)
```

Or just chain them togther:

```
subtraction( multiplication(101) )
```

To start the chain you will need to use a string, int or defined variable. 
Otherwise you get name not defined errors.
**Once a variable is used in a function it goes out of scope when the function ends.**