# how to do a multi dimensional function fitting using python

Tags: python, least-squares

I am doing some least square fitting things. and it's two dimensional which means (x1i,x2i)-->(yi).So far i checked a lot online documents which are designed for 1 dimensional (xi)->(yi).

1  So anyone knows how to solve multi-dimensional least fitting using any standard packages? such as **leastsq**?

2 And the other question is how to return multiple functions!!! The reason I want to do this is just dealing with the **yi-f(xi)** part. If i have limited dataset, i can do something  shown below. But How could i do it with a lot data? I am not able to write every individual function by hand...

```
def F(x):
return (weight(x[0],x[1],x[2],weeknumbers[0])-13,
        weight(x[0],x[1],x[2],weeknumbers[1])-21,
        weight(x[0],x[1],x[2],weeknumbers[2])-28,
        weight(x[0],x[1],x[2],weeknumbers[3])-36,
        weight(x[0],x[1],x[2],weeknumbers[4])-36,
        weight(x[0],x[1],x[2],weeknumbers[5])-39,
        weight(x[0],x[1],x[2],weeknumbers[6])-39,
        weight(x[0],x[1],x[2],weeknumbers[7])-41,
        weight(x[0],x[1],x[2],weeknumbers[8])-42)
```

Comment: You might find numpy helpful. A lot of linear algebra functions already exist there.

Answer (score 0):

For input you can declare multiple arguments "def F(x,y,z):"
for return you can use tuples ([How do you return multiple values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python)) or just return a table: "return [a,b,c]"