# what I should change in this code to return two lists?

Tags: python

```
def ethos(file):
    f = open(file)
    raw = f.read()
    token = nltk.word_tokenize(raw)
    words_to_match = ['love' , 'good' , 'excellent' , 'perfect' , 'brilliant']
    words_to_match2 = ['bad' , 'primitive' , 'struggle' , 'annoying' , 'problem' , 'time-consuming', 'fiddly']
    positive_tokens = []
    negative_tokens = []
    for tokens in token:
        if tokens in words_to_match:
            positive_tokens.append(tokens)
        and tokens in words_to_match2:
            negative_tokens.append(tokens)
    return negative_tokens
```

I wrote this code with an intention of returning two lists one positive and one negative, I cannot give two return statement, but I want two separate lists. And this program is showing syntax error in the 'and' statement, kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last part of your program in the following way:

```
for tokens in token:
    if tokens in words_to_match:
        positive_tokens.append(tokens)
    if tokens in words_to_match2:
        negative_tokens.append(tokens)
return (positive_tokens, negative_tokens)
```

this will return a tuple with two elements. You use it as such:

```
(positive_tokens, negative_tokens) = ethos(yourfile)
```

Comment: ah yes, will add that too

Comment: Note: parentheses are not required, not in the return statement nor in the assignment(apart from the method call of course)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
def ethos(file):
    ...
    positive_tokens = [t for t in token if t in words_to_match]
    negative_tokens = [t for t in token if t in words_to_match2]
    return positive_tokens, negative_tokens
```

You can use this like:

```
positive, negative = ethos("somefile.txt")
```

See [How do you return multiple values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python) for a more advanced discussion on returning multiple values from functions