# How to return multiple values using scipy ndimage.generic_filter in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ndimage, multiple-return-values

I'm looking for a way to output multiple values using the [generic_filter module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html) in scipy.ndimage like so:

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import ndimage

    a = np.array([range(1,5),range(5,9),range(9,13),range(13,17)])

    def summary(a):
        minVal = np.min(a)
        maxVal = np.max(a)

        return [minVal,maxVal]

    [arrMin, arrMax] = ndimage.generic_filter(a, summary,    footprint=np.ones((3,3)))
```

But I keep getting the error that a float is expected.

I've played with the 'output' parameter, like so:

```
    arrMin = np.zeros(np.shape(a))
    arrMax = np.zeros(np.shape(a))
    ndimage.generic_filter(a, summary, footprint=np.ones((3,3)), output = [arrMin, arrMax])
```

to no avail. I've also tried returning a named tuple, a class, or a dictionary, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python) none of which have worked.

Comment: Why are you returning multiple values? From my browsing of examples and docs it looks like it should return a single value. If i understand correctly, the filter makes a new version of the whole image. It doesn't do some kind of summary. Maybe you can describe more in your question what you want to accomplish and the output you expect to get.

Comment: I am processing a large array and I would like to run the filter once and get everything I need as opposed to doing it several times for different returns (e.g., one for min, one for max, etc.).

Comment: Even if it worked that way i doubt you would save very much time. You would still have to "unzip" your result filtered image with all the result values stored at each point. I am not confident but i think you just have to run those filters separately. Again, please update and clarify your question if you think I'm misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, you want to perform multiple filters simultaneously rather than performing them separately.

Unfortunately I do not think this filter works that way. It expects you to return a single filtered output value for each corresponding input value. I looked for a way to do simultaneous filters with numpy/scipy but couldn't find anything.

If you can manage a data flow that allows you to load the image, filter, process and produce some small result data in separate parallel paths (one for each filter), then you may get some benefit from using `multiprocessing` but if you use it naively it's likely to take more time than doing everything sequentially. If you really have a bottleneck that multiprocessing solves you should also look into [sharing your input array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing) rather than loading it in each process.