# Python Function IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python, sql-server, indentation

I'm having issues with an indent error in my code.  It looks correct... can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?  I keep getting the error on the line of my query.

```
def invoice_details(myDeliveryID):

    conn = pymssql.connect(myMSSQLserver, myMSSQLuser, myMSSQLpassword, myMSSQLdatabase)
    cursor1 = conn.cursor()

    cursor1.execute('''My Query''' +  "'" + myDeliveryID + "'" + ''' More of my query...''')

    InvoiceDetails = cursor1.fetchone()

    myLocation = "%s" % (InvoiceDetails[0])
    myDate = "%s" % (InvoiceDetails[1])
    myInvoiceNumber = "%s" % (InvoiceDetails[2])
    myAccountNumber = "%s" % (InvoiceDetails[3])

    return myLocation
    return myDate
    return myInvoiceNumber
    return myAccountNumber

    conn.close()
```

Comment: You can't return 4 things. I think you meant to return a 4-tuple: `return myLocation,myDate,myInvoiceNumber,myAccountNumber`

Comment: There is no indentation error in the shown part of the code

Comment: Okay, I didn't realize you can only have one return.  I still get the same error when returning InvoiceDetails and placing after conn.close()

Comment: You probably want to put your `conn.close()` statement inside your function (i.e. before the return statement). A return statement results in the code leaving the function and returning to the line from which it was called

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple `return` statements in a function.

Instead, you probably meant to return `InvoiceDetails` (which is a tuple):

```
def invoice_details(myDeliveryID):
    conn = pymssql.connect(myMSSQLserver, myMSSQLuser, myMSSQLpassword, myMSSQLdatabase)
    cursor1 = conn.cursor()

    cursor1.execute('''My Query''' +  "'" + myDeliveryID + "'" + ''' More of my query...''')

    InvoiceDetails = cursor1.fetchone()

    conn.close()

    return InvoiceDetails
```

Or, you can make a [`namedtuple()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to also have attribute lookups in addition to positional:

```
import collections

invoice = collections.namedtuple('Invoice', ['location', 'date', 'number', 'account_number'])
return invoice(*InvoiceDetails)
```

Also see:

- [How do you return multiple values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python)

Comment: This has **nothing to do with** the reported problem.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the note!