# how to use returned seperated lists of function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi i have a function which returns a list and a dictionary.
if functions renturns one thing i know how to use that.
but how i can use returned list and dict of function?

my code is :

```
def links(url):
    __url = str(url)  # find_dl_url()
    __page = requests.get(__url)
    __page_content = bs4.BeautifulSoup(__page.content)
    __links = __page_content.select('a[href*=".mkv"]')
    __dict = {}
    __sorted_dict = {}
    __list = []
    for links in __links:
        __dict[links.string] = links.get('href')
        __list.append(links.string)
    __list = sorted(__list)
    print(__list)
    print(__dict)
    return  __list, __dict
```

if function returnes just one list i could write:

```
list=links(url)
```

but how i can get both of list and dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [unpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python) the returned variables

```
lst, dct = links(url)
```