# returning multiple functions

Tags: python, return

This is an example code that is reading off of a pandas dataframe with a names lengths widths, and height, all of which contain floats under each name variable. I am trying to return each of the floats under their respective variable, but I can't seem to figure out how to return multiple variables. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def volume(length, width, height):
    for i in pdf[length]:
        return (i)
    for i in pdf[width]:
        return (i)
    for i in pdf[height]:
        return (i)
```

print (volume('length', 'width', 'height'))

Comment: Is there a missing `def` at the beginning? And shouldn't the rest of the code be indented?

Comment: You can't use `return` multiple times in a function. You should return a tuple with all the values. It's not clear why you have `for` loops, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you return multiple values in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python)

Comment: yea my bad, i messed up when i copied it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a tuple or a dictionary, and assign it to variables:

With a tuple:

```
volume(length, width, height):
    ....
    return (pdf[length], pdf[width], pdf[height])
```

and then invoke the function unpacking the tuple, like this:

```
l, w, h = *volume(x, y, z)
```

or a dictionary

```
return {'length': pdf[length], 'width': pdf[width], 'height': pdf[height]}
```

In which case you can assign the result into a single dictionary variable and reference each value by key (for example: `result['width']`)

And lastly, you could also use an object with 3 separate member variables. If you think it's worth defining a class for your program.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return pdf[length], ...`?

Comment: True. I wasn't clear if he's returning just the 3 dimensions, or a list of 3 dimensions. The for loops confused me. I'll expand the code, and wait for OP to clarify

Comment: Confused me, too.

Comment: My logic was the lists which are put in the object that I am calling have around 7 floats per string name, which is why I used a for loop.

Comment: @bnicholl ok. But how many values or whats the data structure that you expect to return?

Comment: @JavoSN I was trying to return each string argument('length', 'width', 'height') and put them each into their own separate list.