# How to pass variables in python script

Tags: python, function, variables

I have a python script that uses two functions but one of these does not work as desired.
main() calls the first function `Define_and_Collect_1_WireData():` and this works as intended. However I am unable to pass the string variable `data_stream_logfile` from function `Define_and_Collect_1_WireData():` to function `log_file()`.

I have not used `return` as I am not certain that this keeps the variable local rather than global.

I have tried many combinations / variations available on this site: none that I could understand worked.

How can I do this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

# Create a useful time stamp for logging to the log file 
timestamp = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")


def Define_and_Collect_1_WireData():
    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000052c29e1/w1_slave")
    text = tfile.read()
    tfile.close()
    temperature_data = text.split()[-1]
    temperature = float(temperature_data[2:])
    temperature1 = round(temperature / 1000,1)

    #for the purposes of testing. Temperature1 will be pulled from the Dallas 1-wire bus 
    temperature1=13.1

    # Create data_stream_logfile string
    data_stream_logfile = str(temperature1) + "," + str(timestamp)

    # Print output to a terminal
    print "Raw temperature data as written to log file:"
    print data_stream_logfile
    print " "

def log_file():
    # Open the text log datafile
    datafile_temperature_log = open("log_cron_temperature_data.log", "a", 1)
    datafile_temperature_log.write(data_stream_logfile + "\n")
    datafile_temperature_log.close()



def main():

    Define_and_Collect_1_WireData()

    log_file()

main()
```

Comment: You should return it from your first function and pass it into the second function.

Comment: Thanks @quamrana Does it become a global variable if I return it? what does returning it actually do?

Comment: See my answer below. It becomes local to `main()`

Answer (score 3):

You should return it from your first function and pass it into the second function:

```
def Define_and_Collect_1_WireData():
    # stuff...

    # Create data_stream_logfile string
    data_stream_logfile = str(temperature1) + "," + str(timestamp)

    # More stuff
    return data_stream_logfile

def log_file(data_stream_logfile):
    # Open the text log datafile
    datafile_temperature_log = open("log_cron_temperature_data.log", "a", 1)
    datafile_temperature_log.write(data_stream_logfile + "\n")
    datafile_temperature_log.close()



def main():

    data_stream_logfile = Define_and_Collect_1_WireData()

    log_file(data_stream_logfile)

main()
```

So, always, always, **always** do your best to not use global variables!!!!

Comment: Thanks @quamrana If I had 10 variables to pass between these functions, would i return them all, one by one, or is there another way?

Comment: You could return them as parts of an object, or a list or a tuple. It depends how the variables relate to one another. See this **question:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the value of `data_stream_logfile` in the `Define_and_Collect_1_WireData` function and use that to pass it to `log_file()`:

```
def Define_and_Collect_1_WireData():
  ...
  data_stream_logfile = str(temperature1) + "," + str(timestamp)
  return data_stream_logfile

def log_file(data_stream):
  ...

def main():
    data_stream = Define_and_Collect_1_WireData()
    log_file(data_stream)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

# Create a useful time stamp for logging to the log file 
timestamp = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")


def Define_and_Collect_1_WireData():
    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000052c29e1/w1_slave")
    text = tfile.read()
    tfile.close()
    temperature_data = text.split()[-1]
    temperature = float(temperature_data[2:])
    temperature1 = round(temperature / 1000,1)

    #for the purposes of testing. Temperature1 will be pulled from the Dallas 1-wire bus 
    temperature1=13.1

    # Create data_stream_logfile string
    data_stream_logfile = str(temperature1) + "," + str(timestamp)

    # Print output to a terminal
    print "Raw temperature data as written to log file:"
    print data_stream_logfile
    print " "

    return data_stream_logfile

def log_file(data_stream_logfile):
    # Open the text log datafile
    datafile_temperature_log = open("log_cron_temperature_data.log", "a", 1)
    datafile_temperature_log.write(data_stream_logfile + "\n")
    datafile_temperature_log.close()



def main():

    log_file (Define_and_Collect_1_WireData())

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write to a local `data_stream_logfile` and return it to the caller. Then call `log_file(data_stream_logfile)`

Or you could call your `log_file()`in your first function with the argument `data_stream_logfile`.

Or you can make it a global variable to get access from both your functions. Just remember to put `global data_stream_logfile` to each of your functions.

The last one is discouraged since it is error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with scope. When you call `DaC1WD` (because that's a REALLY long function name), it makes a variable within it for the log. When the function finishes, everything within it is lost. What you need to do is `return` the log file and then call the logger with the log file as an arg.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [return values](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pip2/Functions/Returningavaluefromafunction.html) and [parameters](https://www.pythoncentral.io/fun-with-python-function-parameters/) in your functions.  For example you could rewrite your script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

# Create a useful time stamp for logging to the log file 
timestamp = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")


def define_and_collect_1_wire_data():
    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000052c29e1/w1_slave")
    text = tfile.read()
    tfile.close()
    temperature_data = text.split()[-1]
    temperature = float(temperature_data[2:])
    temperature1 = round(temperature / 1000,1)

    #for the purposes of testing. Temperature1 will be pulled from the Dallas 1-wire bus 
    temperature1=13.1

    # Create data_stream_logfile string
    data_stream_logfile = str(temperature1) + "," + str(timestamp)

    # Print output to a terminal
    print "Raw temperature data as written to log file:"
    print data_stream_logfile
    print " "
    return data_stream_logfile

def log(message):
    # Open the text log datafile
    datafile_temperature_log = open("log_cron_temperature_data.log", "a", 1)
    datafile_temperature_log.write(message + "\n")
    datafile_temperature_log.close()



def main():

    log_file(define_and_collect_1_wire_data())

main()
```

Comment: you should rename `data_stream_logfile` to `message` in your `log` function since you are using `message` as your  argument name.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make the variable global as it is currently local to that specific function.

```
global data_stream_logfile
data_stream_logfile = str(temperature1) + "," + str(timestamp)
```

This will make it so you can use it anywhere else in the program

Hope I could help :3

Comment: I wouldn't use a global variable here. Must be avoided as much as possible!