# multiple return from function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def example():
    var1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
    var2 = {'c':3,'d':4}

    return var1,var2

[v1, v2] = example()
```

I want to assign var1 to v1, and var2 to v2. Is it ok for me to unpacked tuple var1,var2 into list v1,v2. So far, I haven't found anyone unpack the multiple return value into list

Comment: refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you return multiple values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

Semantically, there is no difference between unpacking into a list or a tuple. All of these are equivalent:

```
v1, v2 = example()
(v1, v2) = example()
[v1, v2] = example()
```

(See also the [assignment statement grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).)

However, unpacking into a list is a relatively unknown feature, so it might be confusing for people who read your code. It's also needlessly verbose. That's why I would strongly recommend using the well-known unpacking syntax without any parentheses or brackets:

```
v1, v2 = example()
```

Comment: yep bytcode is identical for all 3, e.g. `dis.dis('[v1, v2] = example()')`