# Assigning of multiple variables to a function

Tags: python, function, variables

I have something that I dont understand here. I mean, it works, but I would like to understand what is going on behind the scenes:

```
def load_data():
    f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin1")
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)
```

so, what I am trying to understand is here, in line 3, there are 3 variables(training_data, validation_data and test_data). These are being assigned to one function though!? My question is, what happens to them and/or the function? Is the function executed three times? Or are the variables simply a function then that can be called? Or is the loaded data being split in 3 parts, a third of them being distributed to every variable? I am a noob, so this is probably stupid, but please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called sequence unpacking. You can find it in [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)., where it says:

> The statement `t = 12345, 54321, 'hello!'` is an example of tuple
>   packing: the values `12345`, `54321` and `'hello!'` are packed together in a
>   tuple. The reverse operation is also possible:
>
> ```
> x, y, z = t
> ```
>
> This is called, appropriately enough, sequence unpacking and works for any sequence on the right-hand side.

This feature of the language makes it easy to write functions which seem to return multiple results (although they actually just return a tuple), e.g.

```
def get_three_numbers():
    return 5, 7, 11

a, b, c = get_three_numbers()
```

Answer (score 0):

`pickle.load(...)` is executed **once**. The construct you see is called *unpacking* and is more or less equivalent to

```
result = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin1")
training_data = result[0]
validation_data = result[1]
test_data = result[2]
```

(actually unpacking does one more thing: it assures that `result` has exactly 3 elements) Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

no the function is not performed three times,
but returns values at the same time.

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function) can help you.