# os.popen function not assigning to my var

Tags: python, function

In this code, I am using `os.popopen` to run a background system command.

```
import os
user = "g"

def fetch(): # Gets all the system info via os.system and stores them in variables 
     user = os.popen("""whoami""").read()
fetch()
print(user)
input()
```

You will see that user is first equal to g, normally this is equal to just (" ") but I put it to g to demonstrate. My code should be running my `fetch()` function but it is ether failing bts or my function is not being called, beucase user is always equal to whatever it was before the function (in this case, g). I ran all these lines in the python console and there it works, which makes this really frustrating. What is happening?

(before anyone says anything about how I should be using `subprocesses`, that does not work in my case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the best approach to solve your problem but it makes your code work:

```py
import os
user = "g"

def fetch(): # Gets all the system info via os.system and stores them in variables
    global user 
    user = os.popen("""whoami""").read()
fetch()
print(user)
```

I'd suggest returning the value, for example:

```py
import os

def get_os_user():
    return os.popen("whoami").read()

user = get_os_user()
print(user)
```

If you want to return multiple values from a single function you could:

```py
import os

def fetch_os_details():
    return {
        "user": os.popen("whoami").read(),
        "pwd": os.popen("pwd").read(),
    }

details = fetch_os_details()
print(details)
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained *why* the OP's code doesn't work (e.g. a brief overview of the rules for when a name is local vs. global).

Comment: For the record, on multiple returns, [the typical way of doing it is via `tuple`s, not `dict`s](https://stackoverflow.com/q/354883/364696). If you really want to return with names, you'd make a `collections.namedtuple`/`typing.NamedTuple` type outside the function to return instances of (so you can access the result either by name or by unpacking like a plain `tuple`).