# Python - return dataframe and list from function

Tags: python

I want to create a function in Python that returns both a list and a data frame. I know how to do this with two seperate functions, but is there a way to return both from a single function?

```
import pandas as pd
# sample data
data_dict = {'unit':['a','b','c','d'],'salary':[100,200,250,300]}
# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
# Function that returns a dataframe
def test_func(df):
    # create list meeting some criteria
    mylist = list(df.loc[(df['salary']<=200),'unit'])
    # create new dataframe based on mylist
    new_df = df[df['unit'].isin(mylist)]
    return new_df
# create dataframe from function
new_df = test_func(df)
```

The above function returns just the data frame. How do I also return mylist in the same function?

Comment: return new_df, mylist should return tuple

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return multiple values from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply return two variables in the function

```
import pandas as pd
# sample data
data_dict = {'unit':['a','b','c','d'],'salary':[100,200,250,300]}
# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
# Function that returns a dataframe
def test_func(df):
    # create list meeting some criteria
    mylist = list(df.loc[(df['salary']<=200),'unit'])
    # create new dataframe based on mylist
    new_df = df[df['unit'].isin(mylist)]
    return new_df, my list

# create dataframe and list from function
new_df, mylist = test_func(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

just place comma and add anything you want, but remember in function calling must give same return variables.

```
return new_df, my list

new_df, mylist = test_func(df)
```