# Python function with multiple URLs as input, which outputs multiple DataFrames

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Python function that lets me input multiple URLs, and it will return multiple dataframes, see below.

```
def getdata(*urls):
    for i in urls:
        return pd.read_csv(i,skiprows=4)

derby20, derby19, derby18, derby17 = getdata('https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/data_files/site_data/DESA_2020.csv',
                                             'https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/data_files/site_data/DESA_2019.csv',
                                             'https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/data_files/site_data/DESA_2018.csv',
                                             'https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/data_files/site_data/DESA_2017.csv')
```

However I get the following error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4).

Any idea how I can successfully implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: You're returning the result for the first URL, don't return inside the loop if you want all four.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. Have you tried anything, done any research? See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return multiple values from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning once and never going in function back again. You can use `yield` instead of `return`.

```
def getdata(*urls):
    for i in urls:
        yield pd.read_csv(i,skiprows=4)
```

See this:

```
>>> def foo():
...     for i in range(3): yield i
... 
>>> a, b, c = foo()
>>> a, b, c
(0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! Haven't come across yield before, will have to look into it more!

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines

```
for i in urls:
    return pd.read_csv(i,skiprows=4)
```

to

```
return (pd.read_csv(i, skiprows=4) for i in urls)
```

because after the first `return` command your function will not continue, effectively breaking your loop after the first iteration.