# Return results as separate entities rather than list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def thrust_flow_function(M,r):
  G = (1+r*math.pow(M,2))/(math.pow((1+(r-1)/2*math.pow(M,2)),(r/(r-1))))
  dG = r*G*M*((2/(1+r*math.pow(M,2)))-(1/1+(r-1)/2*math.pow(M,2)))
  return [round(G,5),round(dG,5)]
M = float(input())
r = float(input())
print((thrust_flow_function(float(M),float(r))))
```

In the current code, I'm returning both the values as list. However, when I try to return both the values as separate

`return G return dG`

it only gives me the value of G

Comment: Square brackets have special meaning in Python, where they denote lists. The `dG` formula should likely use parentheses instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. Really appreciate it. Wasted like 2 hrs on this. I thought the error is with the power function.

Comment: There is no need to call `float` so many times. `M` and `r` are already floats. Also, `M*M` is much faster than `math.pow(M,2)`.

Comment: Hey, I got one more doubt... In the current code I'm returning both the values as list (as shown)... `return [round(G,5),round(dG,5)]` However, when I try to return both the values as separate(as shown...`return G` `return dG`), it only gives me the value of `G`

Comment: @Kartik when you hit the first return, the function ends. Returning them as a list is one option. Another is a tuple: `return round(g, 5), round(dG, 5)`

Comment: @nanofarad so if I want the values as separate entities, will I have to run them as separate functions

Comment: @Kartik Return the tuple and unpack it at the receiving end if you need. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36632980/1424875) shows a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets (`[]`) are used to denote lists. You can't use them as general-purpose parentheses like you sometimes do in math. Replace them with good old parentheses in the calculation of `dG` and you should be OK:

```py
dG = r*G*M*((2/(1+r*math.pow(M,2)))-(1/1+(r-1)/2*math.pow(M,2)))
# Here-----^---------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Thanks and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`r*G*M` is producing a `float`, and you're multiplying that by the following anonymous `list` (created due to the use of square brackets, `[]`). You can't do that. Did you mean to use additional parentheses, `()`, instead of `[]`?

Comment: Thanks, I replaced it with round brackets and it worked.

Comment: Hey, I got one more doubt...

In the current code I'm returning both the values as list (as shown)...
'return [round(G,5),round(dG,5)]'

However, when I try to return both the values as separate(as shown), it only gives me the value of G
'return G'
'return dG'

Comment: @Kartik: The function is done when you execute `return`, you can't `return` multiple times (`yield` is kinda like doing that, but it gets used in a different way). Typically, you'd omit the square brackets and just do `return round(G,5),round(dG,5)` [to return multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/354883/364696), as `tuple`s are more efficient for the purpose anyway (you don't need `list` features).

Comment: `
dN = N*((1/M)+((r-1)/2)(M/(1+(r-1)/2*pow(M,2)))-(2*r*M/(1+r*pow(M,2))))
`
This line of code is again giving me that error...**'float' object is not callable**. Now, whats the error. Sorry for asking all the silly questions but I'm new to python.

Comment: @Kartik: Python is not math; you can't just put terms next to each other and get implicit multiplication; you need a `*` where you have `)(` directly adjacent to one another if you want to multiply. Given your (and everyone's) issues with reading complex formulae, I'd suggest breaking them down into smaller bits and storing off partial computations, then operating on those partials (which would also reduce the number of parentheses you need for grouping).

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your guidance.