# return initialized variable as list in python

Tags: python, list, function

I want to initialize `b` and `c` to zero and return output as two list of zeros. but it is returning as tuple

```
def initialize(dim):
    '''In this function, we will initialize bias value 'B' and 'C'.'''
    b = np.zeros(dim)
    c = np.zeros(dim)
    return b.tolist(),c.tolist()
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  If you want a list, then return a list.  How to return items is covered in any tutorial on functions and return.

Comment: want b and c to be the two separate list as b = [0,0,0,0] c = [0,0,0,0]

Comment: Your code should return a tuple of two lists.  What are you getting instead?  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your main program should read something like `main_b, main_c = initialize(50)`

Answer (score 1):

`return b.tolist(),c.tolist()` means a tuple of two lists is being returned; like:

```
([a, b, c], [1, 2, 3])
```

If you instead concatenated the lists together, they would be returned as one list:

```
return b.tolist() + c.tolist()
```

Which returns:

```
[a, b, c, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: want b and c to be the two separate list as
b = [0,0,0,0]
c = [0,0,0,0]

Comment: Okay so what should the function return, then? You said "list of zeros", which I interpreted as "_a_ list of zeros". Are you saying you actually do want to return two lists, but then have the calling code assign the returned lists to two separate variables? Like `b, c = initialize(dim)`? In that case you could keep your original code.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this function the returns will be a tuple of the values so you can set the left hand side like so:

```
b,c = initialize(size)
```

Then b and c will be set from the return of the function.

Comment: If this ends up being the answer, then this question would certainly be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function).