# Multiple return from function call in list comprehension

Tags: python, flatten

I need an explanation about the functioning of Python related to this specific case: I have a list comprehension that calls a function for every element of the `listA`. With this code:

```
listA = [1,1,1]

def operation(n):
    result = []
    *code do something*
    result = [a,b,c]
    return result 

listB = [operation(element) for element in listA]
```

I obtain:

```
listB = [[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c]]
```

How can I return multiple element of a list individually so as to achieve this?

```
listB = [a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c]
```

What I tried is:

```
ListA = [1,1,1]

def operation(n):
    result = []
    *code do something*
    result = [a,b,c]
    for x in result:
        return x
```

Output: `[a,a,a]` instead of `[a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c]`

Note1: ***cannot use any import***

Note2: I put a simplistic case and I cannot transform the list in flat list, what I would need is to be able to return multiple values ​​from a single call, is it possible? Thank you

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate on the items of each returned list to flatten the output:

```
listB = [item for element in listA for item in operation(element)]
```

Note that the order of the `for` expressions is the same as the one you would have if you wrote 'normal' loops.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
listA = [1, 1, 1]

def operation(n):
    result = [i for i in ["a", "b", "c"] * len(listA) for x in i]
    return result

listB = operation(listA)
print(listB)
```

we provide a flatten list when we make a nested for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (for this specific structure of your list, not recommended for some other structures):

```
listB = sum([operation(element) for element in listA], [])
```

Comment: See explanation in 3rd answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists

Comment: That's the answer with this note from the author: "This is inefficient". But with the strange restriction from this question "cannot use any import" it's a way do achieve the desired output.

Comment: I say something similar in my answer too. OP is looking for solutions, not for the best ones only

Answer (score 0):

You could use your function as a generator with a secondary loop through the elements and then iterate over the generator to get your list.

```
listA = [1,1,1]

def operation(n):
    result = []
    ...
    result = ['a','b','c']
    
    ############
    for i in result:
        yield i      #change this to yield
    ############
    
[j for i in listA for j in operation(i)]
```

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to achieve your final output one way of doing it can be by using extend function like this

```
for i in listA:
    listB.extend(operation(listA))
```

this will also generate the same result but it's not a list comprehension

Comment: It should be `operation(i)`. Also, you'll need to define `listB` first: `listB = []`