# How can I return two values from a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, return, return-value

I would like to return two values from a function in two separate variables. 
For example:

```
def select_choice():
    loop = 1
    row = 0
    while loop == 1:
        print('''Choose from the following options?:
                 1. Row 1
                 2. Row 2
                 3. Row 3''')

        row = int(input("Which row would you like to move the card from?: "))
        if row == 1:
            i = 2
            card = list_a[-1]
        elif row == 2:
            i = 1
            card = list_b[-1]
        elif row == 3:
            i = 0
            card = list_c[-1]
        return i
        return card
```

And I want to be able to use these values separately. When I tried to use `return i, card`, it returns a `tuple` and this is not what I want.

Comment: Please provide an example of calling this expected function and using its return value(s), so that it makes clear why you don't want tuples.

Comment: What's the point of the while loop?

Comment: should have an `else: continue` before the return statements

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to return multiple values from a function in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508/whats-the-best-way-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-python)

Answer (score 424, accepted):

You cannot return two values, but you can return a `tuple` or a `list` and unpack it after the call:

```
def select_choice():
    ...
    return i, card  # or [i, card]

my_i, my_card = select_choice()
```

On line `return i, card` `i, card` means creating a tuple. You can also use parenthesis like `return (i, card)`, but tuples are created by comma, so parens are not mandatory. But you can use parens to make your code more readable or to split the tuple over multiple lines. The same applies to line `my_i, my_card = select_choice()`.

If you want to return more than two values, consider using a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). It will allow the caller of the function to access fields of the returned value by name, which is more readable. You can still access items of the tuple by index. For example in `Schema.loads` method Marshmallow framework returns a [`UnmarshalResult`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/2.x-line/api_reference.html#marshmallow.UnmarshalResult) which is a [`namedtuple`](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/fe5469998a6f1f297f8c85acfba8c48ff7bc3d7d/marshmallow/schema.py#L29). So you can do:

```
data, errors = MySchema.loads(request.json())
if errors:
    ...
```

or

```
result = MySchema.loads(request.json())
if result.errors:
    ...
else:
    # use `result.data`
```

In other cases you may return a `dict` from your function:

```
def select_choice():
    ...
    return {'i': i, 'card': card, 'other_field': other_field, ...}
```

But you might want consider to return an instance of a utility class (or a Pydantic/dataclass model instance), which wraps your data:

```
class ChoiceData():
    def __init__(self, i, card, other_field, ...):
        # you can put here some validation logic
        self.i = i
        self.card = card
        self.other_field = other_field
        ...

def select_choice():
    ...
    return ChoiceData(i, card, other_field, ...)

choice_data = select_choice()
print(choice_data.i, choice_data.card)
```

Answer (score 30):

> I would like to return two values from a function in two separate variables.

What would you expect it to look like on the calling end? You can't write `a = select_choice(); b = select_choice()` because that would call the function twice.

Values aren't returned "in variables"; that's not how Python works. A function returns values (objects). A variable is just a name for a value in a given context. When you call a function and assign the return value somewhere, what you're doing is giving the received value a name in the calling context. The function doesn't put the value "into a variable" for you, the assignment does (never mind that the variable isn't "storage" for the value, but again, just a name).

> When i tried to to use `return i, card`, it returns a `tuple` and this is not what i want.

Actually, it's exactly what you want. All you have to do is take the `tuple` apart again.

> And i want to be able to use these values separately.

So just grab the values out of the `tuple`.

The easiest way to do this is by unpacking:

```
a, b = select_choice()
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining "why it is like it is".
Best answer imo.

Answer (score 17):

I think you what you want is a tuple. If you use `return (i, card)`, you can get these two results by:

```
i, card = select_choice()
```

Answer (score 8):

```
def test():
    ....
    return r1, r2, r3, ....

>> ret_val = test()
>> print ret_val
(r1, r2, r3, ....)
```

now you can do everything you like with your tuple.

Answer (score 5):

```
def test():
    r1 = 1
    r2 = 2
    r3 = 3
    return r1, r2, r3

x,y,z = test()
print x
print y
print z


> test.py 
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2):

And this is an alternative.If you are returning as list then it is simple to get the values.

```
def select_choice():
    ...
    return [i, card]

values = select_choice()

print values[0]
print values[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
class select_choice():
    return x, y

a, b = test()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return more than one value using list also. Check the code below

```
def newFn():    #your function
  result = []    #defining blank list which is to be return
  r1 = 'return1'    #first value
  r2 = 'return2'    #second value
  result.append(r1)    #adding first value in list
  result.append(r2)    #adding second value in list
  return result    #returning your list

ret_val1 = newFn()[1]    #you can get any desired result from it
print ret_val1    #print/manipulate your your result
```