# Python No Action on 2nd Statement After 'IF'

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I am trying to loop over a dictionary and call a function on each key.

If the function does not return `None` entry for that key, I want the output to be appended to a list and I also want that key to be appended to a second list.

Here is my code:

```
    output_list = []
    key_list =[]

    for i in dict.keys():
        if obj.method(i):
            output_list.append(obj.method(i))
            key_list.append(i)

    return output_list
    return key_list
```

However, for some reason the second list, `key_list`, is never populated - can you not have two statements below an `if` like the above?

The reason that I am doing this is that I want to eventually produce an output where each key of the dict is listed alongside it's associated function ouput, whenever the output is not `None`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I return two values from a function in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752958/how-can-i-return-two-values-from-a-function-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key_list` is being populated, however you can only return once from a function.

You can return a tuple of results though to return multiple variables. Change:

```
return output_list
return key_list
```

to

```
return output_list, key_list
```

And in the calling code do:

```
output_list, key_list = my_function(...)
```