# button always return the last ID, not the correct one

Tags: python-2.7

I'm creating a menu in [gaffer](https://www.gafferhq.org/) that populate automatically from a string list called "shotlist"

the idea is to have a custom menu for each entry of the list and have an action relative to each entry too, like :

- click on sh001 = sh001
- click on sh002 = sh002
- click on sh003 = sh003

my problem is that my code return :

- click on sh001 = sh003
- click on sh002 = sh003
- click on sh003 = sh003

I understand that when I click on a button, it always return the 3rd value of "shotlist", as it's the last one than the loop worked on, but I dont understand how to set the loop differently to have the right result

actually my code is :

```
def shotSelection( menu ):
shotVar=str(shotName)
print shotName
scriptWindow = menu.ancestor( GafferUI.ScriptWindow )
root = scriptWindow.scriptNode()
root["variables"]["projectshot"]["value"].setValue( shotVar )

root=application.root()
shotlist=["sh001","sh002","sh003"]
for shotName in shotlist:
    GafferUI.ScriptWindow.menuDefinition(application).append("/Pipeline/ShotSwitcher/{0}".format(shotName), { "command" : shotSelection } )
```

I have also tried with the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407865/python-no-action-on-2nd-statement-after-if) but i dont understand well enough how it's work to apply it to my script.

the menu creation part from gaffer works well. but I dont found a way to set up my menu from the list and have the right action on it at the same time

thank you

EDIT:

actually I found the problem but not sure how to fix it

```
GafferUI.ScriptWindow.menuDefinition(application).append("/Pipeline/ShotSwitcher/{0}".format(shotName), { "command" : shotSelection }
```

shotSelection does not transmit any info of the shot clicked on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed my issue with functools(), allowing to transmit the value in each loop