# How to search and return position of a node in a linked list?

Tags: python

new here so sorry if i don't ask this in the right way. So basically I have a linked list and I want to search for a node by it's data using ll.search(data), but I also want to return the position that the node is in so I can insert something right after it. How would I do that?

This is in python.

```
def search(self,item):
    current = self.head
    found = False
    while current != None and not found:
        if current.get_data() == item:
            found = True
        else:
            current = current.get_next()
    return found
```

Here's the code for the search function

Full LL implementation:

```
from Node import Node
class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None    
    def add(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if(node != None):
            node.next = self.head
            self.head = node

    def append(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if(node != None):
            if(self.head == None):
                self.head = node
            else:
                trav = self.head
                while(trav.next != None):#find last node
                    trav = trav.next
                trav.next = node

    def size(self):
        count = 0
        temp = self.head
        while(temp != None):
            count = count + 1
            temp = temp.next
        return count

    def search(self,item):
        current = self.head
        found = False
        while current != None and not found:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                current = current.get_next()
        return found

    def remove(self, item):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while not found:
            if current.get_data() == item:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()
        if previous == None:
            self.head = current.get_next()
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())


    #insert(pos, item) – adds item to position pos >= 1.
    def insert(self, pos, item):
        size = self.size()
        if(pos <= 0 or (size - pos )< -1):
            print("Not enough items in list to insert in that position. Size =",\
                  size, "position = ", pos)
            return False
        if(pos == 1):
            newNode = Node(item)
            newNode.next = self.head
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            count = 2
            probe = self.head
            while(probe != None and count != pos):
                probe = probe.next
                count += 1
            newNode = Node(item)
            newNode.next = probe.next
            probe.next = newNode
            return True

    #popFirst() – removes and returns the first item in the list.
    def popFirst(self):
        if (self.head == None):
            return None
        else:
            curr = self.head
            self.head = self.head.next
            return curr.data

    #pop() – removes and returns the last item in the list.
    def pop(self):
        if (self.head == None):
            return None
        else:
            curr = self.head
            prev = None
            while(curr.next != None):
                prev = curr
                curr = curr.next
            if(prev == None):#only 1 item in the list
                head = None
                return curr
            else:
                prev.next = None
                return curr

    def printList(self, msg):
        temp = self.head
        print(msg, end = ": ")
        while(temp != None):
            print(temp.data, end=" ")
            temp = temp.next
        print()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return head.next == None

    def peek(self):
        if Node.next == None:
            return False
        else:
            return Node.data
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no standard linked list implementation in python so you'll have to show us a code. For generic task of returning multiple data from function call you may simply [return a tuple and unpack it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752958/how-can-i-return-two-values-from-a-function-in-python) .

Comment: In linked-list position is irrelevant. Using the return node you can insert after it.

Comment: Look at how your linked list ```insert``` method works and do something similar.

Comment: If you want to learn "the right way" to ask questions, @yesthisisme - you may want to read http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html.

Comment: Return the `prev.next` node. Then you'd have access to the node's data (or  anything else related to the node).