# tkinter multiple variable return to different labels

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, multiple-variable-return

I am afraid that this is a 'how to' question. I have a function that returns three variables from a text file. I would like to 'print' them to separate label fields so that I can clearly highlight different information.  I have only managed so far to combine them into one return statement using the .format notation. So I want to

```
return date, name, numeric_data
```

and want to be able, in tinter GUI

```
label_name.configure( text = date)
label_name2.configure( text = name)
label_name3.configure(text = numeric_data)
```

At the moment, all I have is:

```
        output = read_clean_format.openfile() # which is return "{}{}{}".format(text,text,text)
        version_result.configure(text = output)
```

Is this possible? Where can I hunt information.

Comment: Don't worry. Have found a (the?) solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752958/how-can-i-return-two-values-from-a-function-in-python

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special you need to do -- have your function return three values, and then use those three values with configure statements like your code seems to show:

```
def openfile():
    ...
    return date, name, numeric_data

date, name, numeric_data = openfile()
label_name.configure(text=date)
label_name2.configure(text=name)
label_name3.configure(text=numeric_data)
```