# How to take multiple values outputted by a function

Tags: python, function, functional-programming

Quick question. For example, let's say that a function outputs two variables in python. So outputA and outputB. How do take outputA and do something with it like add outside of the function.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please show an example of what you want to do with `outputA`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return two values from a function in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752958/how-can-i-return-two-values-from-a-function-in-python)

Comment: so lets say both are array so then how take one output and for example divide it, while the other output i dont do anything. All of this outside the example function above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you return multiple values in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a *tuple* (pair), so use something as

```
    first, second = example(10)
```

and then use `first` to do something with it.

Comment: hang on can i do that with numpy

Comment: It makes no difference - `outputA` and `outputB` may be of arbitrary type, even one type for `outputA` and another for `outputB`.