# optional multiple return values

Tags: python, function, return-value

I have a function that most of the time should return a single value, but sometimes I need a second value returned from the function. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752958/how-can-i-return-two-values-from-a-function-in-python) I found how to return multiple values, but as most of the time I need only one of them I would like to write something like this:

```
def test_fun():
    return 1,2

def test_call():
    x = test_fun()
    print x
```

but calling this results in

```
>>> test_call()
(1,2)
```

and when trying to return more than two, as in

```
def test_fun2():
    return 1,2,3

def test_call2():
    x,y = test_fun2()
    print x,y
```

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "my_module.py", line 47, in test_call2
    x,y = test_fun2()
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I am thinking about something like in matlab, where `x = test_fun()` would result in `x == 1` (while `[x y] = test_fun()` would also work as expected). Is something like that possible in python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use star unpacking to gather all additional return values into a list:

```
x, *y = fun()
```

`x` will contain the first return value. `y` will be a list of the remaining values. `y` will be empty if there is only one return value. This particular example will only work if the function returns a tuple, even if there is only one value.

When `fun` always returns 1 or 2 values, you can just do

```
if y:
    print(y[0])
else:
    print('only one value')
```

If, on the other hand, you want to completely ignore the number of return values, do

```
*x = fun()
```

Now all the arguments will be gathered into the list. You can then print it with either

```
print(x)
```

or

```
print(*x)
```

The latter will pass each element as a separate argument, exactly as if you did

```
x, y, z = fun()
print(x, y, z)
```

The reason to use `*x = fun()` instead of just `x = fun()` is to get an error immediately when a function returns something that isn't a tuple. Think of it as an assertion to remind you to write `fun` properly.

Since this form of star unpacking only works in Python 3, your only option in Python 2 is to do

```
x = fun()
```

and to inspect the result manually.

Comment: not exactly what I was hoping for, but at least with this approach I can avoid indexing a list in the calling function. I guess I will just wrap `test_fun` such that `test_call` wont need to care about the `*y`. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user463035818. Hopefully my update makes things easier for you.

Comment: yes thanks I am still new to python, so any input is welcome. btw the motivation for asking here was to avoid naming the second return value in case I need only the first and I guess `x,*y = ...` is as close as I can get

Comment: @user463035818. Hit refresh. I added a note about just using `*x`

Comment: @ABDUL. This does not work outside py3. Noted in update

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get multiple return values.

Example 1:

```
def test_fun():
    return 1,2

def test_call():
    x, y = test_fun()
    print x
    print y
```

you will get correct output:

```
1
2
```

When you would like to ignore several return values, you can use `*` before a variable in **python3**.

Example 2:

```
def test_fun2():
    return 1,2,3

def test_call2():
    x, *y = test_fun2()
    print x
    print y
```

you will get the result:

```
1
(2, 3)
```