# How does ret, img = cap.read() & similar syntax work in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

Can someone explain to me how such syntax works in python.
From what I know, ret stores a boolean and img stores the next frame, but how is that facilitated.
What other places can such functionality be utilized in Python?

```
ret, img = cap.read()
```

Comment: The function returns a tuple, and Python lets you unpack a tuple into individual components.

Comment: Returning several values in Python can be done by using a `tuple` (which contains at least 2 values). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9752970/3991125) for further details. For unpacking a tuple and multiple variable assignments have a look at [this blog post](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/).