# function not printing coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this code to convert geodetic coordinates to cartesian. It asks for user input and it prints x, y and z.
The code runs without any errors, but after putting the inputs, the print function does not show the value of `x`.

What would be the issue here?

Thank you for your help.

```
import math

a = 6378137                     
f= 0.00335281068
latitude = math.radians(float(input('Enter Latitude:')))
longitude = math.radians(float(input('Enter Longitude:')))
height  = float(input('Enter Height:'))

def earthConverter(latitude, longitude, height):
    N = a / math.sqrt(1-e**2 * math.sin(longitude)**2)
    e = math.sqrt((2 * f) - (f**2))
    x = (N + height) * math.cos(longitude) * math.cos(latitude)
    y = (N + height) * math.cos(longitude) * math.sin(latitude)
    z = (N * (1 - (e**2) ) + height) * math.sin(latitude)
    return x, y, z

    earthConverter(123.0256, 56.45648, 21322.4545)
    print('x is %f' % x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return two values from a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752958/how-can-i-return-two-values-from-a-function-in-python)

Comment: Remember that Python is indentation-sensitive. That means your [mcve] needs to be properly indented.

Comment: As for your problem, your function returns the values, but you never assign the returned values to any variables. Variables in Python are *scoped*, the variables `x`, `y` and `z` that you define in the function are local to that function only.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the intention of your function was not copied correctly. Because the code will not work as shown above. Seems to be a copy&paste error.

To fix the issue you need to store your result returned from the function:

```
def earthConverter(latitude, longitude, height):
    ...
    return x, y, z

x,y,z = earthConverter(123.0256, 56.45648, 21322.4545)
print('x is %f' % x)
```

Comment: indent corrected now. I did store the result as you explained, but still no output here : /

Comment: return x,y,z       x,y,z = earthConverter(123.0256, 56.45648, 21322.4545) 
   print(x)

x does not print.

Comment: You need to remove the intention from your call, just check my answer.

Comment: x prints the value now. I appreciate your response.