# How do you return multiple variables from a function in python

Tags: python

I am creating a game that is played in the terminal and I wanted to reduce the amount of repetitive code by using functions eg

```
def p1_end_turn(p1_turn, p2_turn):
    p1_turn = False
    p2_turn= True
    return p1_turn, p2_turn
```

however when running the program with the code `p1_end_turn(p1_turn, p2_turn)` the variable p1_turn and p2_turn have not been changed. How can I make this code properly return the variables
(im using python3.9.1 and have checked that the function works properly)

Comment: Just returning a variable doesn't change the original. You need to actually _assign_ that returned value.

Comment: If you have variables outside of the function that you want changed, you'd have to set them explicitly to the result of the function (like `a, b = func(a, b)`), or use globals, or use a class to hold the variables and functions. Changing variables' values in a function doesn't change the originals.

Comment: You don't return variables, you return objects. Are you actually trying to rebind the names in the calling scope? Cause that's not a good use for a function. What's the context of this? This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832), especially considering that the parameters are unused. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return two values from a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752958/how-can-i-return-two-values-from-a-function-in-python)

Comment: @Woodford No, OP's already doing that.

Comment: @wjandrea Clearly not as OP isn't assigning the result of the function to anything as described in the answers to the linked question.

Comment: i don't know if it sounds stupid or not, but instead of direct variable define a class that store variable and implement a singleton patteren, so whenever function call then you can change those point value in that class instance

Comment: @Woodford Ah, I see what you mean, but that'd be a different question, like "How do I capture multiple return values from a function?"

Comment: @sahasrara62 That's a good idea to use a class, but why a singleton?

Comment: @wjandrea i am not that good with design pattern, but with singleton, OP can use same instance of class and can change values whenever that class instance is called and sincle there will be only one, then it won't be much difficult to maintain different class instance of same class. this pattern has own disadvantage and OP might need to refactor all code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning a variable doesn't change the value of the variables. I think reading [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp) about variable scope and [this page](https://freecontent.manning.com/mutable-and-immutable-objects/) about immutable and mutable variables would be helpful.
As it has mentioned in second link, boolean variables are immutable objects.
If you really want to stick to your current code (which i highly recommend to first read links and decide what to do!), you can use something like this to change turns:

```
def change_trun(p1_turn, p2_turn):
    return not p1_turn, not p2_turn

# some codes
p1_turn, p2_turn = change_turn(p1_turn, p2_turn)
```

Last line is the key. variables should update with returned values.

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me fix my code and using the links provided I was able to better understand functions (an area I didnt fully grasp till now).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [variable scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/python_scope.asp) (and possibly at [mutable/immutable objects](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutable-vs-immutable-objects-in-python/)). In short you only change `p1_turn` and `p2_turn` inside the function. This means that outside the function the values stay the same.

Comment: This is helpful info, but doesn't really answer the question. How would you use scope or objects to accomplish the desired result?

Comment: If you wanted to change `mutable objects` (lists, dicts, sets, custom classes) your code would work just fine. However for `immutable objects` (strings, ints, ...) I would suggest using @Random Davis' solution.

Answer (score -1):

Your variables in the function are not the same as the ones out of it. Therefore you have to store the output in the variables you want.

```
def p1_end_turn(p1_turn, p2_turn):
    p1_turn = False
    p2_turn= True
    return p1_turn, p2_turn

P1_turn = True
P2_turn = True

P1_turn, P2_turn = p1_end_turn(P1_turn, P2_turn)
```

Comment: This is basically the solution, but the input parameters are still unused, which is bad

Comment: true but again his question is about how to return values from a function which is what was shown

Comment: Yes like Gerry says, I just provided an answer that can solve the problem.