# Multiple Value Return Pattern in Python (not tuple, list, dict, or object solutions)

Tags: python, function, return

There were several discussions on "returning multiple values in Python", e.g. 
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-you-return-multiple-values-in-python), 
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508/whats-the-best-way-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-python).
This is not the "multiple-value-return" pattern I'm trying to find here.
No matter what you use (tuple, list, dict, an object), it is still a single return value and **you need to parse** that return value (structure) somehow.

The real benefit of multiple return value is in the upgrade process. For example,

originally, you have

```
def func():
    return 1
print func() + func()
```

Then you decided that `func()` can return some extra information but you don't want to break previous code (or modify them one by one). It looks like

```
def func():
    return 1, "extra info"
value, extra = func()
print value # 1 (expected)
print extra # extra info (expected)
print func() + func() # (1, 'extra info', 1, 'extra info') (not expected, we want the previous behaviour, i.e. 2)
```

The previous codes (`func() + func()`) are broken. You have to fix it.

I don't know whether I made the question clear... You can see [the CLISP example](https://github.com/hupili/hpl-code-snippets/blob/master/clisp/multi-return-value.cl). Is there an equivalent way to implement this pattern in Python?

EDIT: I put the above [clisp snippets online](http://ideone.com/USlTPP) for your quick reference.

---

Let me put two use cases here for *multiple return value* pattern. Probably someone can have alternative solutions to the two cases:

- Better support smooth upgrade. This is shown in the above example.
- Have simpler client side codes. See following alternative solutions I have so far. Using exception can make the upgrade process smooth but it costs more codes.

---

Current alternatives: (they are not "multi-value-return" constructions, but they can be engineering solutions that satisfy some of the points listed above)

1. tuple, list, dict, an object. As is said, you need certain **parsing** from the client side. e.g. `if ret.success == True: blabla`. You need to `ret = func()` before that. It's much cleaner to write `if func() == True: blabal`.
2. Use `Exception`. As is discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508/whats-the-best-way-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-python), when the "False" case is rare, it's a nice solution. Even in this case, the client side code is still too heavy.
3. Use an arg, e.g. `def func(main_arg, detail=[])`. The `detail` can be `list` or `dict` or even an object depending on your design. The `func()` returns only original simple value. Details go to the `detail` argument. Problem is that the client need to create a variable before invocation in order to hold the details.
4. Use a "verbose" indicator, e.g. `def func(main_arg, verbose=False)`. When `verbose == False` (default; and the way client is using `func()`), return original simple value. When `verbose == True`, return an object which contains simple value and the details.
5. Use a "version" indicator. Same as "verbose" but we extend the idea there. In this way, you can upgrade the returned object for multiple times.
6. Use global `detail_msg`. This is like the old C-style `error_msg`. In this way, functions can always return simple values. The client side can refer to `detail_msg` when necessary. One can put `detail_msg` in global scope, class scope, or object scope depending on the use cases.
7. Use generator. `yield simple_return` and then `yield detailed_return`. This solution is nice in the callee's side. However, the caller has to do something like `func().next()` and `func().next().next()`. You can wrap it with an object and override the `__call__` to simplify it a bit, e.g. `func()()`, but it looks unnatural from the caller's side.
8. Use a wrapper class for the return value. Override the class's methods to mimic the behaviour of original simple return value. Put detailed data in the class. We have adopted this alternative in our project in dealing with `bool` return type. see the relevant commit: `https://github.com/fqj1994/snsapi/commit/589f0097912782ca670568fe027830f21ed1f6fc` (I don't have enough reputation to put more links in the post... -_-//)

---

Here are some solutions:

- Based on @yupbank 's answer, I formalized it into a decorator, see `github.com/hupili/multiret`
- The 8th alternative above says we can wrap a class. This is the current engineering solution we adopted. In order to wrap more complex return values, we may use meta class to generate the required wrapper class on demand. Have not tried, but this sounds like a robust solution.

Comment: Have you considered using a generator (yield)?  If I understand the issue correctly, it seems ideal for this.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, off the top of my head, is to return your second value by mutating a variable that lives in an outer scope. This way, you wouldn't have to return it at all, yet the change will be visible somehow.

Comment: My general rule (formed from painful experiences many years ago) is this: *if you change the interface, change the name too*.  That applies to function calls, file/database formats, bureaucracy form numbers, everything.  A versioned interface ("x = func v1") automatically changes names when changing version numbers ("x, y = func v2") so it falls under one of your "current alternatives".

Comment: @cdarke , I just added it as one alternative solution. Thanks for bring it up.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget , Do you mean 3. and 6. in the "alternative section"?

Comment: Have you considered declaring a class for the return value which inherits the type of the *supposed* result, meanwhile keep the extra return values in the class instance?

Comment: @Shaung , yeah, we used this technique at last. After some evaluation, we think that is the current best workaround without real "multi-value-return" support in the language. I added it as the 8th alternative.

Answer (score 1):

try inspect?

i did some try, and not very elegant, but at least is doable.. and works :)

```
import inspect                                                                    
from functools import wraps                                                       
import re 


def f1(*args):                                                                    
  return 2                                                                      

def f2(*args):                                                                    
  return 3, 3                                                                   

PATTERN = dict()                                                                  
PATTERN[re.compile('(\w+) f()')] = f1                                             
PATTERN[re.compile('(\w+), (\w+) = f()')] = f2                                    

def execute_method_for(call_str):                                                 
  for regex, f in PATTERN.iteritems():                                          
    if regex.findall(call_str):                                               
        return f()                                                            

def multi(f1, f2):                                                                
  def liu(func):                                                                
    @wraps(func)                                                              
    def _(*args, **kwargs):                                                   
        frame,filename,line_number,function_name,lines,index=\                
            inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1]                 
        call_str = lines[0].strip()                                           
        return execute_method_for(call_str)                                   
    return _                                                                  
return liu                                                                    

@multi(f1, f2)                                                                    
def f():                                                                          
  return 1                                                                      



if __name__ == '__main__':                                                        
  print f()                                                                     
  a, b = f()                                                                    
  print a, b
```

Comment: Nice snippet! It can be elaborated into more sophisticated multi-return wrapper. I want to upvote it very much but I don't have the base reputation to do that...

Comment: I made a module based on this solution. https://github.com/hupili/multiret . Just find that I replied to another thread...

Answer (score 0):

Your case does need code editing. However, if you need a hack, you can use function attributes to return extra values , without modifying return values.

```
def attr_store(varname, value):
    def decorate(func):
        setattr(func, varname, value)
        return func
    return decorate

@attr_store('extra',None)
def func(input_str):
    func.extra = {'hello':input_str  + " ,How r you?", 'num':2}
    return 1



print(func("John")+func("Matt"))
print(func.extra)
```

Demo : http://codepad.org/0hJOVFcC

However, be aware that function attributes will behave like static variables, and you will need to assign values to them with care, appends and other modifiers will act on previous saved values.

Comment: This recalls me of the [memorize decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize). In this way, not only the last one, but also all invocations are recorded for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

the magic is you should use design pattern blablabla to not use actual operation when you process the result, but use a parameter as the operation method, for your case, you can use the following code:

```
def x():
    #return 1
    return 1, 'x'*1

def f(op, f1, f2):
    print eval(str(f1) + op + str(f2))

f('+', x(), x())
```

if you want generic solution for more complicated situation, you can extend the f function, and specify the process operation via the op parameter