# Python: How should we write a function to return an object/list and boolean flag

Tags: python, c++

In C/C++, it is common to write a function which returns a success or failure flag and indicates the pass-by-reference object/list is ready to use. For example,

```
bool get_list(List& l)
{
    ...
    if (ready)
    {
        l = m_list
    }
    return ok
}
```

In python, I understand we can return more than one thing in a function but this does not look neat. What is the equivalent way to return the object/list and the boolean flag?

### Edit

Thanks for the comments. I understand we should use exception in modern C++ code but you can see a lot of similar C/C++ code lying around. As mentioned in my question, I know we can return tuple in python (i.e. more than one thing -- sorry for not using the python context). I think I did not use the correct example which leads to the confusion here. For example, it can be something like if you want to return a member variable with list type when it is ready (some condition matches). Instead of returning the list and do the check outside, you can use a flag to indicate if the list is ready to use, which is more efficient.

But as per the below answers suggested, returning tuples is the way to achieve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to return multiple values from a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508/whats-the-best-way-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-python)

Comment: You actually shouldn't be doing this in modern C++ code.

Comment: In C++ we tend to return the object by const reference if possible and throw an exception if things are going pear-shaped.

Comment: I don't think that's *the way*, though. Python has very nice exceptions. I'd say that the idea (**most** of the time) is return only one value and break (throw an exception) if something didn't go ok

Comment: @BorrajaX, sometimes that is just a marriage to problems, sometimes is the solution, lets just stick to answer since there is never a holy grail for everything.

Comment: I didn't write an answer, @Netwave And the OP is saying that it does not look neat. Indeed, it doesn't. And it is rarely used.

Comment: @chesschi i have added another possible solution to my answer, after the new edit you had. it is i think the answer you were looking for

Comment: @JLev I do not mean to return multiple values explicitly. For example, it can mean to return a member object/list when it is ready. I have updated the question to reflect this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in python you can return a tuple of values

```
def get_object(object):
    # start of some code
    code
    # end of some code
    if ok:
        object = something

    return ok, object
```

and then have:

```
flag, result = get_object(myobj)
```

---

after the edit from OP, there's also the possibility of having the get_object be a kind of Mutator function follow the following logic example:

```
class classy(object):
    # this is your object
    def __init__(self):
        self.att = 1
        self.btt = 2

def mutate_obj(classy_obj):
    # this is your get_object for example
    # code
    ok = True  # or False whetever
    if ok:
        classy_obj.att = 10  # or a new classy, or any other object manipulation, on classy_obj
    return ok
```

then:
in ipython:

```
In [4]: myclassy = classy()

In [5]: myclassy
Out[5]: <__main__.classy at 0x3c03250>

In [6]: myclassy.att
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: myclassy.btt
Out[7]: 2

In [8]: flag = mutator_func(myclassy)

In [9]: myclassy
Out[9]: <__main__.classy at 0x3c03250>

In [10]: myclassy.att
Out[10]: 10
```

Comment: In modern C++ (c++17) you have structured bindings, which works similar to have returning a tuple of values: `auto [i, j] = function_that_returns_a_structure_pair_or_tuple_with_two_values();`

Comment: Mutator function is the answer I'm looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged python also in the question I'm gonna go ahead and help you out in python. Introducing tuple unpacking to your rescue (Please do google it out).

```
def do_something(*args, **kwargs):
    some_data_structure = []        # optionally choose whatever DS you want here
    some_flag = False
    # write your logic to change or set the flag
    if some_flag:
       # write some logic here to manipulate your DS now
        some_data_structure.append(1) # just an example
    return (some_flag, some_data_structure)
```

`returned_flag, data_structure = do_something()  # make sure you study about tuple unpacking to understand it`.

But also if you think you need to stick return one param then you can check the elements in your `some_data_structure` if that is empty then it means `some_flag` is False.

Play around and let me know if you need more help!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you want to do is return an optional value. Usually you do not need tuples for that at all because the extra indicator flag is superfluous. Returning `None` is the usual way to indicate *no value*. For example the `get()` method of Python’s built-in dictionaries returns the value if it exists, otherwise `None` (or an explicitly specified alternative value, but `None` is the default.)

This pattern is so common that it is explicitly supported in Python’s new type annotations as `Optional[SomeType]`, which means *either SomeType or None*.

For that reason, unless you need `None` for something else, the most idiomatic way to solve your problem is:

```
def get_list():
    if ready:
        return the_list
    return None
```