# what does 0 mean? how can it have three items

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, return

I have trouble understanding these lines of codes:

```
return (0, user, computer)        
return (-1, user, computer)
```

My question: what does 0, -1, and 1 mean? How can () have three items inside?

Thanks very very much!I'm a beginner. Much help is needed and appreciated.

the original code is below:

```
def play():
    user = input("What's your choice? 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors\n")
    user = user.lower()

    computer = random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])

    if user == computer:
        return (0, user, computer)         #?????????????????

    # r > s, s > p, p > r
    if is_win(user, computer):
        return (1, user, computer)

    return (-1, user, computer)
```

Comment: This is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq). These questions and answers might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508/whats-the-best-way-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354883/how-do-i-return-multiple-values-from-a-function

Comment: The function is returning a data structure known as a "tuple". Here's an example of what it can do: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/tuple

Comment: As for what do the numbers mean, that's a program logic thing (they have no intrinsic meaning), but I'm assuming it's indicating tie, user lost or user won for 0, -1 and 1 respectively.

Comment: worth noting that this is really strange code. You shouldn't expect to write things that look like this.

Comment: Use of this tuple to represent the end state is something I'd expect to be a stand-in for a real solution that involves a custom `Result` object or etc

Comment: @AdamSmith: A `collections.namedtuple` would be the usual approach (as code that relied on the `tuple` would still work, and new code could access named attributes if it preferred).

Comment: @ShadowRanger yup, or a new-fangled dataclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `-1` means the user lost, `0` means it's a draw, and `1` means the user won. `()` stands for a tuple, a type of data structure that's a iterable. The `return` statement can return *any* type of object in Python.

See: [Python docs on tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions first:

> what does 0, -1, and 1 mean?

0 : draw;
1 : user wins;
-1: user loses (computer wins)

> How can () have three items inside?

in python, when you put the things you return between parenthesis, you are returning a `tuple`.

To sum up, this code asks the user to choose (rock, paper, scissors) then the computer randomly chooses one too. The two choices are then sent to `is_win` which decides the game outcome.