# Loading MNIST data in Keras in python, what is being done with mnist.load_data()

Tags: python, keras, mnist

In my machine learning with python textbook, there is this section of code:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
```

I understand that the goal of this was to import the mnist training images, labels, and test images and labels but what is being done in the second line? Are those arrays and if they are what would they look like / what type of data holding mechanism is it? How would we know to what set mnist.load_data() is being assigned to?

Comment: Your first question can be easily answered by running the code and examining the variables in python, I dont' understand your second question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I meant are they lists, tuples, etc. What is the syntax for assigning the output of the method?

Comment: This probably answers your question, its a python feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508/whats-the-best-way-to-return-multiple-values-from-a-function-in-python

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks - they don't have this in Java haha